# React native checkbox paper not checking individually

Tags: firebase, react-native, mobile

I am currently building a todo list productivity application and using the checkboxes from https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/checkbox-item.html
Im looping through my users todos through firebase and added a checkbox for each.  However, when they check it, all of the todos get checked, not the invididual one.  What would be the solution?
Code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {useState} from "react"
import { SafeAreaView, Text, View, Button, TouchableOpacity, Modal, StyleSheet,Pressable, TextInput,ImageBackground, Image, ScrollView,  } from 'react-native';
import { collection, doc, setDoc, query, getDocs, onSnapshot, addDoc, orderBy, limit, Timestamp, where} from "firebase/firestore"; 
import {db} from "../firebase"
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { Checkbox } from 'react-native-paper';
import {signPlsOut} from "../firebase"

export  const Dashboard = () => {
  const image = { uri: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/901614276748402820/946157600041476176/Screen_Shot_2022-02-23_at_4.32.16_PM.png" };
  const {uid, photoURL, displayName} = auth.currentUser;
  const projectsref =  collection(db, "projects");
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const q = await query(projectsref, where('uid', '==', uid), orderBy("createdAt"))
      onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        let todos = []
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {todos.push(doc.data())})
        setProjects(todos)
      })
    }
    getData()
  }, [])
  async function handleAddTask () {
    try {
      await addDoc(projectsref, {
        title: title,
        desc: desc,
        createdAt: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
        uid: uid,
      }) 
      setTitle("")
      setDesc("")
      setModalVisible(false)
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
      // ADD THIS THROW error
      throw error;
    }
  }
  return (
   <SafeAreaView style={{
    flex: 1,
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    margin: 20,
    flexDirection: "column", 
  }}>
     <View style={{
       flex: 1,
       marginTop: 20
     }}>
        <View style={{marginBottom: 20, display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
          <View style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row"}}>
          <Image source={{uri: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856542608171073616/947245168191496212/Screen_Shot_2022-02-26_at_4.33.30_PM.png"}} style={{width: 50, height: 50}}></Image>
          <View style={{marginLeft: 20, display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 17, fontWeight: "700"}}>{auth.currentUser.email}</Text>
            <Text style={{color: "grey", fontSize: 15}}>Good Morning </Text>
          </View>
          </View>
          <View style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center"}}>
            <AntDesign name="search1" size={24} color="black" />
            <Feather name="bell" size={24} color="black" style={{marginLeft: 10}}/>
          </View>
       </View>
       <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Add task:</Text>
            <View style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
              <TextInput placeholder='title' value={title} onChangeText={(text) => setTitle(text)} ></TextInput>
              <TextInput placeholder='description' value={desc} onChangeText={(text) => setDesc(text)}></TextInput>
            </View>
            <Button title='submit todo' onPress={handleAddTask}></Button>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Cancel</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: "#EEE6DF", flex: 1, padding: 10, borderRadius: 20, marginBottom: 20, }}>
         <Text style={{
           fontSize: 30,
           fontWeight: "700"
         }}>Create Daily Tasks </Text>
        <View style={{display: "flex", flexDirection:  "row", flexWrap: "wrap", alignItems: "center"}}>
        {projects.map((doc, key) => (
          <View key={key} style={{
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            borderRadius: "20px",
            padding: 10,
            marginTop: 20, 
            width: 130, 
            marginLeft: 20
          }}>
            <Checkbox
            status={checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
            onPress={() => {
              setChecked(!checked);
            }}
           />
          <Text style={{
            color: "#000",
            fontSize: 30, 
            fontWeight: "700"
          }}>{doc.title}</Text>
          <Text style={{
            color: "#000",
            fontSize: 20
          }}>{doc.desc}</Text>
        </View>
     ))}
            <Button title='Sign Out' onPress={signPlsOut} style={{marginLeft: 100}}></Button>
        </View>
       </ScrollView>
     </View>
     <View style={{
         display: "flex",
         alignItems: "center",
         justifyContent: "center",
         flexDirection: "row", 
       }}>
         <TouchableOpacity >
         <Pressable
        onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
           <AntDesign name="pluscircle" size={50} color="#8BF45B" />
        </Pressable>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a state for each ToDo separately.

For this, you can create an array state to store the id's wich ToDo are checked

```
 const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([]);

 {projects.map((doc, key) => (
      <View key={key} style={{
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderRadius: "20px",
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 20, 
        width: 130, 
        marginLeft: 20
      }}>
        <Checkbox
        status={checked.find((item) => item === doc.id) ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'} 
        onPress={() => {
         if(checked.find((item) => item === doc.id)) {   //Verify if the ToDo id exist on checked state
           setChecked(checked.filter((item) => item !== doc.id));  //Sets the checked state to an array without the current doc.id
         } else {
           setChecked([...checked, doc.id)]   // add the current ToDo doc.id to the checked state
         }
        }}
       />
      <Text style={{
        color: "#000",
        fontSize: 30, 
        fontWeight: "700"
      }}>{doc.title}</Text>
      <Text style={{
        color: "#000",
        fontSize: 20
      }}>{doc.desc}</Text>
    </View>
 ))}
```

This logic was the one I could think of now, I don't know if it is the best way but I hope it helps

Comment: its given me a error: checked.find() is not a fucntion?

Comment: any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: Did you have added the empty array on checked state inicialization?
const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(  **[ ]**  );

Comment: it fixed it kind of but when you press the checkbox it chekcs for a second before disapearing